# how to add textbox to GTK+ Menu?

Tags: python, gtk

does anyone know how you can add a textbox or other controls to a gtk menu Item? I want do this to my Indicator application like Rhytmbox adds such control in it's indicator menu on linux(well it adds some button instead of textbox but we are still on the same page right?).
thanks

Comment: ok, seem's it's not possible for now
[http://askubuntu.com/questions/55290/how-do-i-add-a-slider-to-an-appindicator][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55290/how-do-i-add-a-slider-to-an-appindicator

Comment: It is advisable to answer your question yourself and accept it.  It will benefit everybody.